# Is it possible to receive an Amazon SNS message on a JS script?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I know some options using ruby on rails and/or node.js and PubNuB, a service that has many APIs so you can send/receive notifications between (almost) any platform.

I now how to send messages from PHP and how to receive them there using Amazon SNS, but how can I receive a push notification (a SNS message) on a JS/jQuery script?

Thanks.

Comment: Does Amazon SNS support web sockets?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, but not directly and you'll have to poll for messages on a timer...

In the [Product Details page](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/details/) under the heading "Flexible", you'll see that none of the currently supported formats/transports can be hosted in the browser.

However... [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) is one of the supported transports, and it in turn can be accessed from JavaScript - see an example app here: http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-SQS/1254.  (The example shows JavaScript accessing SQS).

You'd have to manually poll though, as there is no "push" to the browser with SQS.

(Alternatively, you could do it all server-side, and then you could use potentially use websockets to push the messages to the browser.)

Comment: Is it possible that AWS SNS still does not support websockets?!

Comment: @DraškoKokić, it is unlikely that SNS will ever directly support WebSockets. WebSockets require a long-lived connection. SNS caters for Push notifications.

Comment: The answer is correct but the link does not work anymore... to see the latest sdk examples the following link can be used:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sqs_code_examples.html

Answer (score -2):

Use a service worker in your project and set up a Push Notification handler... I created a GCM project and made a little node.js server and it seems to receive messages from SNS... No polling required.

Comment: You should provide more detail on *how* do this.