# Amazon SNS: Notify browser client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have long running task and I would like to update the progress to the client running a desktop browser.  I want to use Amazon SNS for this. However, I've yet to find any examples or guides on how to do this.

I am using python on my backend. As the process runs, I want to post to Amazon SNS, which will then fire back to the client.

Comment: SNS is a _push_ notification service. For your client to respond to it, it must either have a HTTP listener or you push the SNS notification to a server, which your script can poll it from. The latter seems to be the only option when you want to use SNS as the client/browser can't act as a server (it would need to be subscribed and verified first too). You'd be better off using SQS (Queueing service, which your client could poll directly), I suppose.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624619/is-it-possible-to-receive-an-amazon-sns-message-on-a-js-script

Comment: You may also give a try to [Bow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[deepstream.io](https://deepstream.io/) is a nodejs server for publishing AWS SNS messages directly to the browser. It's mechanism is long-polling https and wss.

Link to their tutorial: [Publishing AWS SNS messages to browsers](https://deepstream.io/tutorials/getting-started/javascript/)